# Swift showing view only on first launch with navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar

I have some code to only show the first view controller in my storyboard on the first launch of the app. After that I want to skip that page and go straight to my second view on each launch. I have embedded the first view (which is connected to the second) in a navigation controller.

My issue is that after the first launch when the app goes to the second view directly it's showing the view without the navigation bar on top and I'm not sure why.

In my appdelegate:

```
func firstLaunchCheck(){
        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore{ 
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialView : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainScreen") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialView
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
    else{

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** 
I wound up just changing which view controller were embedded in the navigation controller (excluded the first one) since it didn't make sense to me to have it there. So now after the first launch it loads the navigation controller

Comment: @jcka the vc2 should embed in a navigation controller, and the second in you should go to the navigation controller whose top vc is the vc2.

Comment: because in second time you skip the first view controller that have the navigation bar . if you want to show the navigation bar second time   you have to add it on second view controller also

Answer (score 0):

`SecondViewController` is not added in `UINavigationController` hierarchy, to see the `navigationBar` on top you can push `SecondViewController` on firstVC if the launchedBefore is false in appDelegate

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController 
let navigationController = window.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed the second view controller i.e. "mainScreen" in UINavigationController and then make it the rootViewController of your app window.

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainScreen"))
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = initialView
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```